# Can GPS location be acquired in a phone without internet and SIM?

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to develop an android application which can acquire GPS location without using Internet and even network location using SIM. Actually, SIM will be inserted in phone and i know that location upto 500m accurate can be acquired through it. But in case of no SIM signals in the area, is it possible to acquire location?

Comment: Yes, this is possible if device has GPS chip. Obtaining a lock can take MUCH longer though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use GPS without any external data connection because signals from the GPS satellites are receive-only.

On a device, the permission setting is known as [device-only location mode](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3467281?hl=en):

> **Device only**
>   This mode uses only GPS. It doesn’t use Google's Location service to provide location information. It can estimate your device's location slower and use more battery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can get the coordinates but for using map services you need internet.The only thing is your GPS will take a bit longer to lock your location on a cold start, and it might not be quite as accurate.

It's a aGPS (Assisted GPS), and get's part of the location information from the data network (If available) on cold start, then fine-tunes the location further than what a GPS alone can do.

Shouldn't be an issue however, really. Just turn your GPS on a little sooner (Like while getting ready to leave, not waiting until you are in your car).

Comment: `and it might not be quite as accurate`. Nonsense. Only gps is accurate. Without gps is never accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you use the Location Manager, set the Provider to LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER. If you use Google Play Services, it should work automatically.